# Sleep no longer in cstdlib?

Tags: c++, linux

I have an application that has normally compiled fine.  It uses two "non-standard" functions (both in cstdlib if I'm not mistaken):  sleep() and daemon().  Upon updating my system I discovered my program will no longer compile (it still compiles on an older system of mine).   GCC gives me this message:

```
error: 'daemon' was not declared in this scope
error: 'sleep' was not declared in this scope
```

I remember once in the past I had this same issue with sleep() and including cstdlib resolved the problem.  I cannot find a change log for cstdlib and have no idea where the function was moved to (if not removed).  I am also assuming the same thing happened to daemon().  I cannot find anything related to this in google.

Does anyone know where these went, or better yet know where I can find out in the future in case I run into this problem yet again?

I know daemon() is a lazy way of doing things, and could write a proper way to daemonize this program myself (using fork and such), but using it is so convenient.

Comment: Have you tried 'man 3 sleep' or 'man daemon'? - Since linux man pages give the header files for these functions

Comment: @AdrianCornish, no I did not...and now feel kind of dumb...I'll post back if I find anything

Comment: Do you have the option to use c++11

Comment: @CountMurphy never feel dumb for not knowing :-) or never be afraid to ask a question - we have all been there

Comment: Ok, chrono and thread libs. provide a standard sleep but it is relatively new and I'd rather not supply more issues if you can't

Comment: By "cstdlib" do you mean the C standard library or the C++ header `cstdlib`?

Comment: Most UNIX/Linux specific functions will be in `<unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux man pages often include the header files needed for most functions try

```
man daemon
```

or

```
man 3 sleep
```

Both of which probably say that you need `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: While both answers are correct (and upvoted), I'm accepting this one because it told me how to discover information like this on my own

Comment: @CountMurphy Thanks fish and fishing and all that ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Neither `sleep` nor `daemon` are part of the C standard library (cstdlib). `sleep` is a POSIX.1-2001 function defined in `unistd.h` and `daemon` is a non-POSIX function which is also available in `unistd.h` on linux.

As a non-standard function you may have to define `_GNU_SOURCE` before `#include <unistd.h>` to get the definition of the `daemon`.

Comment: +1 because your answer is better even though mine was accepted